# How does inverse function theorem show how interior or boundary points map?

Tags: inverse-function-theorem

So I've read many references that make proofs about **interior points mapping to interior points and boundary points mapping to boundary points** and they all seem to cite that the inverse function theorem proves this.

However, upon viewing Wikipedia's page for inverse function theorem,

I'm unable to conclude, where or how exactly does IVT say this?